# 3 node Cassandra with RF = 2, in two DCs. How do i ensure data is replicated between DCs?

Tags: cassandra

DC1 has R1 and R2. DC2 has R3. Its an A/A test setup. Write can happen on R1, R2, R3 - but neither  should  replicate to locally. Any thoughts?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your snitch and strategy. The following article may be of help -

http://www.onsip.com/blog/2011/07/15/intro-to-cassandra-and-networktopologystrategy

You can use "nodetool getendpoints" to check the replicas.